# Валидация одно input на Email или телефон одновременно

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток, не подскажите как сделать валидацию одновременно и на телефон и на email, пробовал вот так, ничего не получилось, валидирует только email

Html:

```
<form id="form1" action="/booking" method="post" role="form" class=" subscribe">
<input type="text" id="room" class="form-control" name="BookingForm[email]">                
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="a0R3SzZudWYSB1oBYF4SBwg3My5xACBTKSUfE3lfGSQzKD0gXRQ.MQ==">                
<span class="email_error"></span>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Отправить">
```

Jquery

```
          var valid= true;
        if(email == ''){
            valid = false;
            jQuery('#room').addClass('error');
        }else{
            var re = /^[0-9]*$/;
            var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
            if (!re.test(email)){
                valid = false;
                jQuery('#room').removeClass('error');
            }

            if(valid == false && !pattern.test(email)){
                    valid = false;
                    jQuery('#room').addClass('error');

            }

        }
```

Comment: Добавьте полную часть кода (включая HTML), относящуюся к данной проверке полей

Comment: добавьте console.log() в каждую ветку двух условий чтобы увидеть, как работает код

Comment: Добавил Html елси это чем то поможет

Answer (score 0):

```
var valid= true;
        if(email == ''){
            valid = false;
            jQuery('#room').addClass('error');
        }else{
            var int_ = jQuery('#room').val();
            var re = /^[0-9]*$/;
            var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
            if (!re.test(int_)){
                valid = false;
                jQuery('#room').removeClass('error');
            } elseif (re.test(int_)) {

            } elseif (!pattern.test(jQuery('.#room').val())){
                valid = false;
                jQuery('#room').addClass('error');
            } else {

            }
        }
```